# Android - Read big file from external storage

Tags: android, multithreading

If I have to read a big file from a external storage, such as SDCard, I know i should do it in a separate thread, but my question is: If I do so on the main thread, will it cause a exception similar to "NetworkOnMainThreadException"?

I know that Network exception will always happen, but I imagine that if the read is too long, something my cause a exception or maybe cause android to shut the app down...

I'm asking this because right now I'm unable to test it since my android device does not have a external storage and my dev machine is SSD (which speed things up a lot...)

Details:
 - In real scenario, the files can be as big as a couple of GB...

Comment: All devices have external storage. And a lot have removable SD card storage too. Please don't mix them up.

Answer (score 1):

No you won't get an exception if you are using straight file input streams, but you will probably get an ANR. This allows the user to then kill the process and exit your application.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html